# How to add a new column based on summation of other columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the total number of all injuries **per row**, but the code below is giving me the total injuries for all rows

```
flights$Total.Injuries =  sum( flights$Total.Fatal.Injuries,
                           flights$Total.Minor.Injuries,
                           flights$Total.Serious.Injuries,na.rm = TRUE )
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: you should post you `str(flights)` or even better, a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rowSums(flight, na.rm=T)`,

or  `rowSums(cbind(flights$Total.Fatal.Injuries, flights$Total.Minor.Injuries, flights$Total.Serious.Injuries),na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
flights$Total.Injuries <= rowSums(flights[ , c(x, y, z)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

where 
    x = column number for Total.Fatal.Injuries,
    y = column number for Total.Minor.Injuries,
and 
    z = column number for Total.Serious.Injuries

Answer (score 1):

Or another option is `Reduce` with `+`

```
flights$Total.Inuries <- Reduce(`+`, flights)
```